# When I multiclass Sorcerer/Wizard do I unlearn a cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, multi-classing, sorcerer

I was thinking of making my level 6 sorcerer part wizard. But at level 6 my Sorcerer knows *5 cantrips* and looking at the multiclass spell table, he'd have *4* when he's a *7th level multiclass caster.*

Does he forget 1 cantrip?

Comment: The table you are referencing is the table of spell *slots* per level, not spells known. Also, the value of 4 you are mentioning is for Lv1 Spells, not for cantrips

Comment: @Cristol.GdM You should post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Cristol.GdM On the other hand, if the character is as old as I am, he may have forgotten one.  8^D (But I think effects of aging might be an optional or variant rule ...)

Comment: @Szega Dale M's answer already covered everything I would have said, didn't see the point in repeating it. And I try to avoid using answers to point out wrong assumptions in the question

Answer (score 7):

PHB p. 164

> You determine what spells you know and prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single classed member of that class.

Your Sorcerer 6/Wizard 1 knows 5 Sorcerer cantrips and 3 Wizard. For completeness, you know 7 Sorcerer spells and 6 Wizard.

Comment: Ohh, I see my mistake! Thought the far left column on that table was cantrips, but it's 1st level spells.  ^^' My bad.

Thanks!

Comment: Notably, @Lockles, that table describes spell _slots_, not spells _known_.