# Do Cantrips stack when you multiclass Spellcasting class of the same casting type (Wizard, Edlrich Knight, Arcane Trickster)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing, cantrips

Do Cantrips stack when you multiclass Spellcasting class of the same casting type (Wizard, Edlrich Knight, Arcane Trickster)?

Ex: Lv 10 Arcane Trickster has 4 cantrips & Lv 10 Wizard has 5. Does the mean this PC knows 9 cantrips?

> [When I multiclass Sorcerer/Wizard do I unlearn a cantrip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98032/when-i-multiclass-sorcerer-wizard-do-i-unlearn-a-cantrip)

Sadly this did not help as they used two different spellcasting type.

Comment: Related (duplicates?): "[Cantrips for each multi-class class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59158)" and "[When I multiclass Sorcerer/Wizard do I unlearn a cantrip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98032)" and "[If I multiclass into 2 or more spellcasting classes, how do I determine my known/prepared spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/151000)"

Comment: You say "this did not help as they used two different spellcasting type." But what makes you think anything would change by multiclassing with Wizard, Arcane Trickster, and Eldritch Knight? What makes those multiclass builds different from Sorcerer + Wizard?

Comment: You’ve been asking a lot of questions that have been asked before, I would recommend doing some searching around the site before asking your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dale M notes in the question you linked, pg 164 of the Player's Handbook has the answer:

> You determine what spells you know and prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single classed member of that class.

So a level 10 Wizard/level 10 Arcane Trickster has 9 cantrips in total, 5 from Wizard, 4 from Arcane Trickster.